# Nextjs Pages Router converted to App Router

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

This is an API written using Nextjs's Pages Router. The function is to proxy downloads. Now I want to convert it to the App Router method. How can I implement it?

```
import axios from 'axios'
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

type TQuery = { url: string; name?: string }

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method !== 'GET') return res.status(404).end()

  const { url, name } = req.query as TQuery

  if (!url) return res.status(500).end()

  try {
    const filename = name || url.split('/').pop()

    const controller = new AbortController()
    const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'stream', signal: controller.signal })

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${filename}`)

    response.data.pipe(res)

    const close = () => {
      response.data.destroy()
      controller.abort()
    }

    res.on('close', () => close())
    res.on('error', () => close())
  } catch (error) {
    res.redirect(url)
  }
}
```

I wish there was an example of App Router conversion.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for your question: "How can I implement it?"

1. Identify the different between "Page Route" and "App Route"

Page route: expects you have 1 single function `handler` for an endpoint name no matter what method is.

```
function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {}
```

App route: expects you have multiple function. Each one mapped to a single method

```
function GET(request: Request) {}
function POST() {}
```

2. Pick the corresponding one

Lucky for you right at the beginning you have

```
if (req.method !== 'GET') return res.status(404).end()
```

This means you are expected to handle `GET` method only

So just copy the rest of your `handler` function into the `GET` function

```
function GET(request: Request) {
    // the rest of the code
}
```

3. Fix the differences of `NextApiRequest` of page route and `Request` of app route

Now search StackOverflow again for how to get `query` from `Request` object of App Route of Next 13.

4. Fix the differences of `NextApiResponse` of page route and `Reponse` of app route

Check offical document https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers

the `GET` function expect to have `Response` return.

Thing will be nearly identical.

If something mismatch, search StackOverflow again for that specific mismatching.